# CommunityToolkit.MVVM Dependency Injection with Blazor

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, community-toolkit-mvvm

I would like to use CommunityToolkit.MVVM functionality within Blazor specifically
[image]

Currently documentation refers to UWP.

1)

[image]

How do we replicate this line in a Blazor minimal startup ?
[image]

Minimal startup example
[image]

as I would like to use something like this.

[image]

2)

When I also use the IOC methods that the toolkit provide then it throws an error that "services have not been configured"
[image]

So I can add services with following line but then I have 2 service instance running ( 1 through normal DI and one for MVVM)
as I would also like to use cascading values in razor.

[image]

I ultimately want to use either of the following 2 statements without duplicating services. Preferable the Ioc.Default.GetService() method

[image]

[image]

I'm probably wrong but to me it looks like I can't use MVVM with current Blazor defaults. If someone can point me in the right direction here it would be appreciated.